# htaccess Rewrite two subdirectories to root

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have the following htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/v1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/v1/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ site/v1/ [L]
```

So when I access either `domain.com` or `www.domain.com`, I go directly to `domain.com/site/v1`, without the `/site/v1` part showing on the browser.

But my problem is that inside the `site/v1` folder, there's a `admin` folder, containing the website's CMS, and when I access `domain.com/admin`, it redirects to `domain.com/site/v1/admin`, with the `/site/v1` part being displayed on the browser.

So, my question is, how I can get to access the `/site/v1/admin` folder without displaying all the path, i.e., when I access `domain.com/admin`, it access the subfolder, but doesn't display it?

In other format, I have:
 - I access `domain.com/about`
 - On the server side, I'm actually at `domain.com/site/v1/about`
 - On my browser I see `domain.com/about`
 - ps: `about` here is a parameter being passed to my back-end via a RewriteCond directive (on another piece of code), not being a folder (but it works just as well with a folder)

What I too have:
 - I access `domain.com/admin`
 - On the server side, I'm actually at `domain.com/site/v1/admin`
 - On my browser I see `domain.com/site/v1/admin`

What I want:
 - The last item before to be "I see `domain.com/admin`"

Thank you!

**EDIT**

Here's my full htaccess file after the changes:

```
# force ssl
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/v1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/v1/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^admin/$ /site/v1/admin/ [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ site/v1/ [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to rewrite the base url is to us a rewrite rule like this.

```
RewriteRule ^$ /site/v1/ [L]
```

To solve your admin directory issue, just add and additional rule like this.:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/$ /site/v1/admin/ [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it still doesn't work, it behaves the same (I tried cleaning the cache, different browsers and computers - just to make sure).
I edited my post with my full htaccess file.

Comment: What CMS are you using?

Comment: I developed it on my own